# how to update ember-cli app to ember-data 1.0.0-beta9?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have an ember-cli application. It seems like ember-cli uses ember-data `1.0.0-beta.8.2a68c63a` at the moment by default. (at least thats loaded into the browser with `ember serve`)

But i wanna use the [current](http://emberjs.com/builds/#/beta) `beta.9`, because the recent changes on `DS.DateTransform`.

How can I update my ember-data version?

Its confusing because ember-data seems to be installed twice! Once with bower (but I have no dependency in my bower.json), and once with npm (but here the ember-cli-ember-data).

The installed version with bower seems to be `1.0.0-beta.10` (why 10? On emberjs.com only 9 is listed!), but the `ember-cli-ember-data` npm modules has a ember-data `1.0.0-beta.8.2a68c63a` loaded.
A recent change on the [github repo](https://github.com/twokul/ember-cli-ember-data) is telling me that is now deprecated, and I should update my package.json, but how, and why is ember-cli not doing that for me?

Thanks for help to install `ember-data 1.0.0-beta.10`!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To update to the latest version of `ember-data` you should run

```
npm uninstall ember-cli-ember-data --save-dev
npm install ember-data --save-dev
```

The reason for the change is that `ember-cli-ember-data` was just a wrapper package which was being used to include `ember-data` into an `ember-cli` project. `ember-data` was recently updated to be able to be able to be used an `ember-cli` addon without needing a wrapper package (which is why `ember-cli-ember-data` is being deprecated).

The issue you are seeing with `ember-cli-ember-data` is because `ember-cli` changed the way that it loaded bower dependencies. It used to merge files from both the `vendor` and `bower_components` directories.

The way `ember-cli-ember-data` worked was...

- `ember-cli-ember-data` placed a default version of `ember-data` (which was beta.8) in the the `vendor` directory
- you were able to update the files in the `bower_components` directory by specifying a newer version in your `package.json`
- the `bower_components` directory would get merged into the vendor directory (with your updated version replacing the version from `ember-cli-ember-data`)
- `ember-cli-ember-data` then imported the `ember-data` files from the vendor directory

Now that the `bower_components` directory is not being merged into the `vendor` directory what is happening is that `ember-cli-ember-data` always loaded its version from the vendor directory (which is why you are getting beta.8)

Comment: Thanks, thats working, and that informations are very interesting! So why is it finally the idea to load `ember-data`, as a clinet-side dependency, with `npm` rather then `bower`?

Comment: The reason why you need to npm install and not just bower install is because `ember-data` is being both as a bower package and as an `ember-cli` addon. The confusing thing about the way things currently work is that the `ember-data` addon will always load the version from `bower_components` so if in `package.json` you specify beta.10 and in `bower.json` you specify beta.6 then you would end up with beta.6 even though you npm installed beta.10. Once you npm install `ember-data`, to update you need to update the version of `ember-data` in your project the bower package, not the npm package.

Comment: Very interesting! Thank you very much! Just where is it specified for bower to install `ember-data`? Its not listed in my bower.json, but bower *does* install `ember-data` if i delete the folder and execute `bower install`.

Comment: it is probably being installed as a dependency of a different package. If you run `bower ls` you should be able to see a dependency graph which should show why `ember-data` is being installed. If you want to fix your project to a specific version of ember data, you should run `bower install ember-data --save`

Comment: If its the first time your adding `ember-data` to the project you can also use the `ember-data` generator to add the bower dependency to your bower.json. So instead of running `bower install ember-data --save` you can run `ember generate ember-data`.